# Android : how to refresh TableLayout data while switching from one tab to other?

Tags: android

I have two tabs. One tab shows all the data fetching from DB using TableLayout.
From the other tab I enter data into DB. So now when I switch tab I should see the the new data from DB. 
As per my understanding I need to write my code inside :

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
              if( tabId.equals("showData") ){

              }
            }
        });
```

But how can I refresh the TableLayout that is present in Activity of other class.
Can someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Write the that updates the table in a method of it's own, then call that method when the tab is changed